# Thread Dump Analyzer

Tags: java, multithreading, analyzer, thread-dump

Do you know some good thread dump analyzer tool? Perfect would be :

- free
- can read a few thread dumps and compare them
- point out which threads took the longest, what are the classes that the thread is locked on etc.
- shows threads, locks, deadlocks and multiple threads waiting to acquire a single lock

Edit:

- offline analyze - load file with one or many thread dump and analyze it.

**Edit:**
My choice is: Samurai. It has all the features I need: Loads logfile, and compares few thread dumps. Analyze it and points:

- waiting threads
- blocked threads
- blocking threads
- deadlock

I'll leave question as answered because TDA is the best answer that was given.

Comment: i found the spotify thread dump analyzer helpful http://spotify.github.io/threaddump-analyzer/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use TDA - Thread Dump Analyser, a plug-in for Visual VM.

Visual VM is free as well. I think this is your best choice.

> If you are on Linux you could use kill -3 to get a thread dump and
>   look for deadlocks using using Thread Dump Analyzer.
>
> VisualVM now ships as part of the JDK and can be used monitor memory
>   usage, threads and also includes a profiler.
>
> jmap can be used to obtain heap histograms and heap dumps from Java
>   processes. You could then use a tool like Eclipse Memory Analyzer to
>   investigate it.
>
> As another answer mentioned you could look into JMX and JConsole. For
>   each service in our application we have a MBean so we can view keys
>   stats such as queue sizes to check if anything seems out of the
>   ordinary.

From [Tools and tips for Sun JVM troubleshooting](https://serverfault.com/questions/5944/tools-and-tips-for-sun-jvm-troubleshooting) on ServerFault.

Comment: As far as I see, in visualvm I cannot do offline analize. Did I missed something? In my case I cannot connect analizer to running instance.

Comment: @AugustinGhauratto how are planning to get the threads without connecting to the running instance ?

Comment: On linux: kill -3 java_instance_pid , generates thread dump to console log. I cannot afford to give an instance with heavy load more burden. And I don't have physical possibility to do so - sshd has forwarding disabled, and visualvm as far as I did investigate it is graphical tool.

Comment: Any advice on how to install this on VisualVM/JDK 1.8.0_144 (and in other newer versions, I suspect)? It doesn't appear in the [plugin update listings](https://visualvm.github.io/pluginscenters.html). The wiki [recommends to download it manually](https://github.com/irockel/tda/wiki/12.-VisualVM-Plugin#wiki-body) from the "TDA website", but [the site](https://tda.dev.java.net/) seems to be long gone... And there are no release artifacts in the [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/irockel/tda/releases/) either :(

Answer (score 3):

In case you use IBM JRE you should use **[IBM Thread and Monitor Dump Analyzer for Java](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/alphaworks/tech/jca)**, which offers exactly what you need (offline use, comparisons etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could try my [Dump Analyzer](http://java-apps.org/content/show.php/Dump+Analyzer?content=164188). I had the same need and developed my own dump analyzer. It has some of the features of your list.

Comment: I don't understand why should be a comment, my answer is like the rest of answers... every answer is offering an app for analyzing threads dumps. By the way, the project is now on Github: [https://github.com/sergiocormio/dump-analyzer](https://github.com/sergiocormio/dump-analyzer)